Error using Nuitka: call to '/usr/bin/codesign' failed
I am trying to create an executable from .py file using Nuitka, but "code sign error" shows up.
code:
nuitka --enable-plugin=tk-inter --follow-imports --standalone --onefile --macos-create-app-bundle tkinter.py

error code:
FATAL: Error, call to '/usr/bin/codesign' failed: 
'/usr/bin/codesign', '-s', '-', '--force', '--deep', '--preserve-metadata=entitlements', 
'tkinter.app/Contents/MacOS/tkinter'] -> b'tkinter.app/Contents/MacOS/tkinter: 
resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed'.

OS: macOS 15.1.1.
I tried to fix the preferences on keychain access, but wasn't sure how to do it.
I found out that "my certificate" in my keychain access is empty, but is it okay?
(keychain access > login > my certificates)
I am thinking of requesting a certificate, but it seems that I have to join the Apple Developer Program which costs.
I have "Basic Attestation User Sub CA1" in my "certificate" file.
(keychain access > login > certificates)
